# Move Div Only With JS HTML CSS [Need to Improve the code and possibly shorten it]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built this code and I want to improve it and maybe shorten it a little bit. I thought maybe replace the `switch` in Shorten IF and it did not work.
I would be happy to help thanks.

```js
let positionL = 200;
let positionT = 200;

function moveDiv(e) {
  var div = document.getElementById("Circle").style;
  switch (e) {
    case "left":
      div.background = "blue";
      positionL -= 5;
      if (positionL <= 55) {
        div.background = "red";
        positionL = 55;
      }
      div.left = positionL + "px"; // left
      break;

    case "up":
      div.background = "blue";
      positionT -= 5;
      if (positionT <= 55) {
        div.background = "red";
        positionT = 55;
      }
      div.top = positionT + "px"; // up
      break;

    case "right":
      div.background = "blue";
      positionL += 5;
      if (positionL >= 345) {
        div.background = "red";
        positionL = 345;
      }
      div.left = positionL + "px"; // right
      break;

    case "down":
      div.background = "blue";
      positionT += 5;
      if (positionT >= 345) {
        div.background = "red";
        positionT = 345;
      }
      div.top = positionT + "px"; // down
      break;

    case "reset":
      positionL = 200;
      positionT = 200;
      div.background = "blue";
      div.left = positionL + "px";
      div.top = positionT + "px";
      break;

    default:
      return;
  }
}
```

```css
.Continer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  left: 400px;
  top: 400px;
}

#Divcontainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
}

#Circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.Controller {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Continer">
  <div id="Divcontainer">
    <div id="Circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Controller">
    <button onclick="moveDiv('up')">^</button><br /><br />
    <button onclick="moveDiv('left')">
          <
        </button>
    <button onclick="moveDiv('right')">></button><br /><br />
    <button onclick="moveDiv('down')">v</button>
    <button onclick="moveDiv('reset')">reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What specifically did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: If the code works, then it is a question for codereview

Comment: I would extract all the div.background calls and the boundary check in a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaned up your JS a bit:

```js
let positionL = 200;
let positionT = 200;
let bounds = {
  left: 55,
  top: 55,
  right: 345,
  bottom: 345
};

function moveDiv(e) {
  if (e === "reset") {
    positionL = 200;
    positionT = 200;
  } else {
    // this implementation will be advantageous when you start using keyboard inputs 
    // and multiple directions can be pressed at the same time; even contradicting ones
    // like left AND right
    positionL += 5 * ((e === "right") - (e === "left"));
    positionT += 5 * ((e === "down") - (e === "up"));
  }

  var red = positionL <= bounds.left ||
    positionL >= bounds.right ||
    positionT <= bounds.top ||
    positionT >= bounds.bottom;

  positionL = Math.max(bounds.left, Math.min(bounds.right, positionL));
  positionT = Math.max(bounds.top, Math.min(bounds.bottom, positionT));

  var div = document.getElementById("Circle").style;
  div.left = positionL + "px";
  div.top = positionT + "px";
  div.background = red ? "red" : "blue";
}
```

```css
.Continer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  left: 400px;
  top: 400px;
}

#Divcontainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
}

#Circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all ease-in 150ms;
}

.Controller {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Continer">
  <div id="Divcontainer">
    <div id="Circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Controller">
    <button onclick="moveDiv('up')">^</button><br /><br />
    <button onclick="moveDiv('left')">&lt;</button>
    <button onclick="moveDiv('right')">&gt;</button><br /><br />
    <button onclick="moveDiv('down')">v</button>
    <button onclick="moveDiv('reset')">reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!
I want to move the DIV diagonally and add more buttons for that you can help me?